# Is there a way to make transparent / invisible PHP redirects?

Tags: php

I use this snippet here:

```
<?php
    $uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/name/source/class.ControlEntry.php')
    exit;
```

However all that path information ends up in the url.  Is there a way to redirect with out showing the path information in the browser's url?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking for can you clarify where you want the redirect to go and what url you want displayed to the user?

Comment: I believe your .htaccess file would be able to handle something like this, but I don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: I just want the domain shown http://www.domain.com

Comment: But I still want to go to the path in the question.

Comment: include_once would be more secure in one regard as it would hide path information an attacker might use...assuming that it would work.

Comment: @CS_2013, it's a very bad practice to include files over http. Read secutiy warning here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: How is it being included by HTTP?..it's just a path change...this is all on one server.

Comment: @CS_2013 Using include() for this is really, really insecure.

It's possible for the user to modify the HTTP_HOST request header and if your script is blindly including it I could make your application run whatever code I wanted.

eg: I set the request header to send 'somenastydomain.com' as the HTTP_HOST and on my own server (somenastydomain.com) I write my own script located at /name/source/class.ControlEntry.php.

All of a sudden your application is running my code & I have control of your server.

Comment: Well, you'll need to change $uri to local server path, not http. Then it'll be fine to use include.

Comment: will do....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344823/how-do-i-format-a-php-include-absolute-rather-than-relative-path

Answer (score 0):

1) Your web server can do the redirect. For this solution, you have to be able to configure your webserver. See here:
[Help with mod_rewrite and mod_redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917220/help-with-mod-rewrite-and-mod-redirect)

2) You can use frames. Put a file similar to the following to your first web site and refer to the second web site.

```
<html>
  <frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="URL OF SECOND PAGE HERE">
  </frameset>
</html>
```