# want to remove paramters from url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

want to remove paramters from url using htaccess 
My url look like this

```
http://localhost/details?id=179&title=abcdefghij
```

i want to convert it like this (or any better suggestion)

```
http://localhost/details/179/abcdefghij
```

Please help me how can i acheive it

Comment: Learn to use google. This question was answered many times. Open initial configuration step of any modern PHP framework and it'll  have your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with mod\_rewrite and mod\_redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917220/help-with-mod-rewrite-and-mod-redirect)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I match query string variables with mod\_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

To convert `/details?id=123&title=foobar` to `/details/123/foobar` you can use the following rule in `root.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1  redirect "/details?id=123&title=foobar" to "/details/123/foobar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /details/?\?id=([^&]+)&title=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /details/%1/%2? [L,R]
#2 internally rewrite the requested url "/details/123/foobar" to "/details?id=123&title=foobar"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^details/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /details?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```